# Sorting objects by field availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a `place` object that has the following parameters: `phone`, `category`, `street`, `zip`, `website`.

I also have an array of `place` objects: `[place1, place2, place3, place4, place5]`.

What's the best way to sort the  array of `place`s, based on the parameter availability? I.e., if `place1` has the most available parameters, or the least number of parameters that are `nil`, it should be reordered to first and so on.

**Edit: These objects are not `ActiveRecord` objects**

Comment: DO you want to sort them by the number of fields that are filled? Is it what you mean by `parameter`?

Comment: exactly. Also it would be nice to weight some of the fields higher than others. For example, having a `street` or `zip` is more important than `phone` or `category`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd let each Place object know how complete it was:

```
class Place
  attr_accessor :phone, :category, :street, :website, :zip

  def completeness
    attributes.count{|_,value| value.present?}
  end
end
```

Then it is easy to sort your place objects by completeness:

```
places.sort_by(&:completeness)
```

---

**Edit:** Non-ActiveRecord solution:

I had assumed this was an ActiveRecord model because of the <kbd>Ruby on Rails</kbd> tag. Since this is a non-ActiveRecord model, you can use `instance_variables` instead of `attributes`. (By the way, congratulations for knowing that domain models in Rails don't have to inherit from ActiveRecord)

```
class Place
  attr_accessor :phone, :category, :street, :website, :zip

  def completeness
    instance_variables.count{|v| instance_variable_get(v).present?}
  end
end
```

---

**Edit 2:** Weighted attributes

You have a comment about calculating a weighted score. In this case, or when you want to choose specific attributes, you can put the following in your model:

```
  ATTR_WEIGHTS = {phone:1, category:1, street:2, website:1, zip:2}

  def completeness
    ATTR_WEIGHTS.select{|k,v| instance_variable_get(k).present?}.sum(&:last)
  end
```

Note that the `sum(&:last)` is equivalent to `sum{|k,v| v}` which in turn is a railsism for `reduce(0){|sum, (k,v)| sum += v}`.

Comment: Yeah it's a lot cleaner, but you have to select the attributes you want from the object that may have a lot more attributes and add ponderation by having some sort of constant holding ponderation values!

Comment: It's not hard to make those adjustments. It'd still be clean.

Comment: you just need to call reverse at the end or use .sort do |a,b| b <=> a end

Comment: I think this post assumes that the values are stored in the database. I'd like to not stoer if possible.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily require any database storage. However `attributes` comes from ActiveRecord. If this is not an ActiveRecord model, then you can define `completeness` to be `instance_variables.count{|v| instance_variable_get(v).present?}`

Comment: This is not an ActiveRecord model.

Comment: OK, I've made a couple of edits to make my answer more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but this is a start :

#### ruby fat one liner

```
values = {phone: 5, category: 3, street: 5, website: 3, zip: 5} #Edit these values to ponderate.
array = [place1, place2, place3, place4, place5]

sorted_array = array.sort_by{ |b| b.attributes.select{ |k, v| values.keys.include?(k.to_sym) && v.present? }.inject(0){ |sum, n| sum + values[n[0]] } }.reverse
```

So we're basically creating a sub-hash of the `attributes` of your ActiveRecord object by only picking the key-value pairs that are in the `values` hash and only if they have a `present?` value.

Then on this sub-hash, we're invoking `inject` that will sum the ponderated values we've put in the `values` hash. Finally, we reverse everything so you have the highest score first.

To make it clean, I suggest you implement a method that will compute the score of each object in an instance method in your model, like mark suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class `Place`:

```
class Place
  attr_accessor :phone, :category, :street, :website, :zip
end
```

and you create an instance `place1`:

```
place1 = Place.new
place1.instance_variables      # => []
place1.instance_variables.size # => 0

place1.phone = '555-1212'      # => "555-1212"
place1.instance_variables      # => [ :@phone ]
place1.instance_variables.size # => 1
```

And create the next instance:

```
place2 = Place.new
place2.phone = '555-1212'
place2.zip   = '00000'
place2.instance_variables      # => [ :@phone, :@zip ]
place2.instance_variables.size # => 2
```

You can sort by an ascending number of instance variables that have been set:

```
[place1, place2].sort_by{ |p| p.instance_variables.size }
# => [ #<Place:0x007fa8a32b51a8 @phone="555-1212">, #<Place:0x007fa8a31f5380 @phone="555-1212", @zip="00000"> ]
```

Or sort in descending order:

```
[place1, place2].sort_by{ |p| p.instance_variables.size }.reverse
# => [ #<Place:0x007fa8a31f5380 @phone="555-1212", @zip="00000">, #<Place:0x007fa8a32b51a8 @phone="555-1212"> ]
```

This uses basic Ruby objects, Rails is not needed, and it asks the object instances themselves what is set, so you don't have to maintain any external lists of attributes.

Note: this breaks if you set an instance variable to something, then set it back to `nil`.

This fixes it:

```
[place1,place2].sort_by{ |p|
  p.instance_variables.reject{ |v|
    p.instance_variable_get(v).nil? 
  }.size
}.reverse
```

and this shortens it by using Enumerable's `count` with a block:

```
[place1,place2].sort_by{ |p|
  p.instance_variables.count{ |v|
    !p.instance_variable_get(v).nil? 
  }
}.reverse
```